# How To Remove Background image of Multiple UIButtons At Once?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uibutton, background-image

I use 20 UIButtons in my application .i set the background image of all these UIButtons on click event.all these UIButton are save in NSMutableArray.here is code.

```
             saveBtn = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
             for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
             UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
             btn.frame = CGRectMake(spacex, spacey, 30.0, 30.0);
             idx = arc4random()%[arr count];
             NSString* titre1 = [arr objectAtIndex:idx];
             [btn setTitle:titre1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];   
             spacex = spacex + 30;
             [saveBtn addObject:btn];
             [self.view addSubview:btn];
          }
```

i don it successful here is my code.

```
 UIButton *currentButton = (UIButton *)sender;
 UIImage * imgNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"subtabButton.png"];
 [currentButton setBackgroundImage:imgNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [currentButton setTitle:currentButton.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

But between these 20 UIButtons there are 3 UIButtons ,i want that when player click one of these three UIButtons,all the previous set background images are remove from UIButtons.can any one guide me how we can do it..thanx in advance.

Comment: Why won't a loop over all the UIButtons work?  Put them in an array and have at them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (UIButton *btn in yourArrayOfButtons)
{
   [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nameofmyimage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

or if you want to remove the image:

```
for (UIButton *btn in yourArrayOfButtons)
{
   [btn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: he wants to remove the image.

Comment: He asked how to do a for loop to iterate over his buttons.

Comment: +1 to counter the minus 1. He did ask to remove it to be fair though.

Comment: Thank you.  I updated my post to reflect his original question.

Comment: +1 for fixing your code. I'm not an idiot for marking you down, it asked for it to be removed.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll remove my rude comment. haha

Comment: But in for loop when i click on one UIButton its automatically assign the all the UIButtons Background image..i want to set back ground only on click event of that specific buttons

Comment: my coding second part set the back ground image succesful for each button.but i an unable to remove background image at once.

Comment: @Inturbidus its works as i want..but i was need only second part of u r coding thanx..

Answer (score 2):

Put all the buttons in an NSArray or NSMutableArray when they're created. Then use a for-in loop, or a simple for loop to change the background for all of them.

Comment: @melsam i already save all these buttons in NSMutablearray..can u give the idea about for loop how can i remove these images using for loop..

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this is create each button dynamically. Store each buttons information into an NSMutableArray then do a for loop to remove the images.

```
 [currentButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

would remove the button's image. Its kind of hard to help you without seeing how your buttons are stored in an array.

Comment: @johan i already save all these buttons in NSMutablearray..can u give the idea about for loop how can i remove these images using for loop..

Comment: can it remove all the previous setbackgroundimage of UIButtons.?

Comment: But in for loop when i click on one UIButton its automatically assign the all the UIButtons Background image..i want to set back ground only on click event of that specific buttons.

Comment: my coding second part set the back ground image succesful for each button.but i an unable to remove background image at once.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you have 20 buttons, where 3 of those buttons remove the Image for the other 17.

If the 3 that control this function are in the array, i suggest you remove them from it because looping over your array of buttons will also remove the images from the 3 `main` buttons.

Alternatively you should use a `tag` to differentiate the 3 main buttons. Your button(s) action should look something like this.

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

      UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

      if(button.tag == 1001 || button.tag == 1002 || button.tag == 1003) {

             for (UIButton *btn in buttonArray) {
                [btn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
             }

       }


}
```

I may be misunderstanding your need, but this is what I came up with. Hope it helps !